# Angular 2 can not access this on observable callback

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
onLogin(): void {

  this.message = "loading";

  this.api.login("username", "password")

    .subscribe(
      this._processData,
      this._logError,
      //error => { this._logError(error); },
    );

}

private _logError(data) {
  console.log(data);
  this.errorMessage = data.message;
};
```

When I uncomment the line with `//error ->` and comment the line above, everything works fine.

It would be nice if there is a direct call solution where I give the function directly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it's a problem related to the use of the `this` keyword itself within JavaScript and TypeScript. See this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript.

You can try to use the `bind` method, as described below:

```
onLogin(): void {
  this.message = "loading";

  this.api.login("username", "password")
    .subscribe(
      this._processData.bind(this),
      this._logError.bind(this)
    );
}

private _logError(data) {
  console.log(data);
  this.errorMessage = data.message;
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 5):

> When I uncomment ... everything works fine

Well, your `_processData()` method must not not be trying to read or write to any component property, since it will not have the proper/expected `this` context.  With  `.subscribe(this._processData, ...)`, the `this` context in `_processData()` will be a Subscriber object, not your component.

I suggest you use the [arrow function](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows-and-lexical-this) for both the success and error callbacks to get the "same lexical `this` as the surrounding code" -- i.e., to get `this` to be the component:

```
.subscribe(
  data  => this._processData(data),
  error => this._logError(error),
);
```

I find this to be cleaner than using `bind()`.

Comment: Yes agreed with you Mark ;-) I prefer to use arrow functions for the subscribe callbacks...